# MAPILogonEx 80040111 from WCF application

Tags: wcf, mapi

I am trying to use the MAPI libraries from a WCF service application under the LocalService identity, but keep on getting the 0x80040111 MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED error.

As suggested by https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181739, I have enabled Log on locally for the given user.

Do you know where could this be coming from?

Comment: What is in the profile used by MAPILogonEx?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Basically, I am talking about an exchange server profile with an exchange account and a server address

Comment: Is your code running under the identity of the domain user who owns the mailbox? If not, the Exchange provider cannot prompt for rte. credentials, so the login fails.

Comment: No, I am running under the identity of the LocalService user. Unfortunately, I cannot impersonate the owner of the mailbox. One solution I am thinking of is to create a new profile inside the web application - while impersonated with LocalService -. However, I am not sure if I can do this without any user input

Comment: Impersonation does not work well (if at all) with MAPI. You really need to have the process running as the owner of the mailbox. If you are using RPC-over-HTTP, you can cache the credentials. Have you looked at Redemption and its RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox (old RPC style) and RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox (RPC-over-HTTP)?